# How system integration happens with an ESB?

Tags: api, integration, middleware

Assume I have two different software sub  systems and I need to interconnect them through an Enterprise Service Bus.

What sort of modifications do I need to make in the existing systems to integrate this ESB?

For example assume vendor A developed System A, and vendor B developed system B. In order to make these two communicate with each other through an ESB what should vendor A developers do, and what should vendor B developers do?

This is what I have understood so far.

In order to connect to the ESB, system A acts as a web service client and the ESB acts as a web service provider. Then the ESB forwards the message to the system B after mediating the message as needed.

For this to work the existing systems need to be modified to act as web services clients and web services. All the systems can expose their needed functionality as web services and when messages needs to be sent they should act like clients. So there needs to be some modifications done in both systems. Correct me where I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

The ESB must be able to call the functions of A and B using their exposed API's. So each system must expose an API using a protocol that the service bus can use. A web service is possible, but ESB's support many.

Then the ESB should expose services in the best format that external systems can consume. So what the ESB exposes does not need to be the same as A and B expose themselves.

In the end system A and B call services on the ESB and the ESB calls the systems that implement the exposed business functions.

One of the reasons to use an ESB is to hide the implementation of the underlying systems in the network. An other reason is to create single points in the network where business functions can be invoked.

Comment: Would this also work if the system is externally provided by another company with their own custom protocol?

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to interconnect only 2 enterprise system, there is no need for ESB. Think about direct connection. Any way additional mediation that ESB is add some drawbacks to overall effectiveness. I think in case of 2 system integration ESB will act as unnecessary  overhead.